# How to parse xml into a table veiw

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, uitableview

Im new to IOS from Android and am wondering how to parse xml with several tags into a listview. and once that has been parsed have the click action launch a detail webview with the url from the link tag.Here is one of the lists. a rough guideline or a tutorial would be amazing.  http://graffiti.hostoi.com/00Graffiti00/lists/arts.xml

it looks like this in android [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link for parse xml parse

```
NSString *url=@"http://www.lancers.jp/work/search/.rss";

NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSDictionary *dict=[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:nil];
```

[Check this link also](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/)

[Demo code of XML](http://ge.tt/2isB62h1/v/0?c)

Comment: thanks for the tutorials. you wouldn't know how to parse in an image aswell, would you?

Comment: @user3381665 get thumb_url from dictionary.that's also call image parse